# can´t start ocsmanager in openchange

Tags: linux

I compiled and installed openchange. Started samba and then:

```
make ocsmanager-install
make pyopenchange
make pyopenchange-install
```

All ok without errors, but when I try to run

```
paster serve /etc/ocsmanager/ocsmanager.ini --pid-file /var/run/ocsmanager.pid --log-file /var/log/ocsmanager.log
```

It aborts and logs this (in log file):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/paster", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.5', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 104, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 143, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 238, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/serve.py", line 284, in command
    relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/serve.py", line 321, in loadapp
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 56, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ocsmanager/config/middleware.py", line 43, in make_app
    config = load_environment(global_conf, app_conf)
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ocsmanager/config/environment.py", line 157, in load_environment
    mstore = mapistore.MAPIStore(config['ocsmanager']['main']['mapistore_root'])
SystemError: error in mapistore_init
Removing PID file /var/run/ocsmanager.pid
```

My /etc/ocsmanager/ocsmanager.conf is the installed by make scripts with the only change of the location of mapistore:

```
mapistore_root = /usr/local/samba/private
mapistore_data = /usr/local/samba/private/mapistore
```